# How to remove the payment method in magento2

Tags: magento2.2, onepage-checkout, payment-methods

I want to remove the selected **Payment Method** on page reload (or) load in checkout page(FrontEnd).

Comment: How about disable from admin area?

Comment: Please describe your question.

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: use javascript to hide selected payment method on page load

Comment: But , its throws  Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 1):

try this code.

add `events.xml` in `Vendor\Module\etc\`

```
<event name="payment_method_is_active">
    <observer name="hide-payment-method" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Paymentactive" />
</event>
```

and in `Paymentactive.php` observer add this code.

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {

    $method = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance();
    $result = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
    $paymentCode = $method->getCode();
    if ($paymentCode == 'your_method_code') {
        return $result->setData('is_available', false); //hide method

    }
    return $result->setData('is_available', true);

}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 // Remove selected payment method on page onload
            initialize: function () {
                var deferred = $.Deferred();

                //Remove selected payment method from quote
                quote.setPaymentMethod(null);
                //Remove selected payment method from localstorage
                checkoutData.setSelectedPaymentMethod(null);
                //Refresh payment section
                getPaymentInformation(deferred);

                var self = this;
                this._super();
            },
```

Comment: Do you know how to remove loader when selecting payment method?